# Spring data cannot select book entity without me printing it in console

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I have controller for selection book entity:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public String bookPage(@PathVariable int id, Model model){
    if(bookService.isExist(id)) {
        //System.out.println(bookService.getById(id));
        model.addAttribute("book", bookService.getById(id));

        return "books/book";
    }
    return "books/noSuchBook";
}
```

If I add attribute "book" without printing it first in console then I get blank webpage.
Here is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title th:text="${book.getName() + ': ' + book.getAuthor()}"></title>
</head>
<body>

<p th:text="${book.getId() + ', ' + book.getName()}"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

If I call `System.out.println(bookService.getById(id));` before adding it, it works. Do I need set Eager type somewhere or what?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that `bookService.getById(id)` delegates to `JpaRepository.getById()` which in fact returns a proxy with id, not a real entity. When you pass it to `System.out.println()` then `toString()` method is called forcing Hibernate to fetch the data from the database and store it in its 1st level cache, so subsequent calls to `getById()` deal with already loaded entity.

I think you need to use `JpaRepository.findById()` eagerly getting the entity, not its proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the best practice but I've resolved my problem by creating my own method in interface BookRepo and setting `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN);` on it.

```
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
Book findBookById(int id);
```